# Google Appscript - how to set conditional format with multiple ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this problem. I tried to use 'for loop' to set multiple ranges with one function but got error message.

'Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder.setRanges.'

Here's my code.

```
function myFunction() {

let columnStart = ['d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','aa','ab','ac'] 

let columnEnd = ['d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','aa','ab','ac','ad','ae','af','ag','ah','ai','ai','ai','ai','ai','ai','ai','ai','ai']

let range='';
let formula ='';
let rule = '';

let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetname')

for(let z=0; z<columnStart.length;z++){

formula = '=sum($'+columnStart[z]+'6:$'+columnEnd[z+6]+'6)>=40'
range += '[';

  for(let i=3; i<25; i++){
    if(i!=24){
      range += "sheet.getRange('"+columnStart[z]+2*i+':'+columnEnd[z+6]+2*i+"'),"
    }else{
      range += "sheet.getRange('"+columnStart[z]+2*i+':'+columnEnd[z+6]+2*i+"')"
    }
  }

  range += "]"

  Logger.log(range)

  rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().whenFormulaSatisfied(formula).setBackground('#f4cccc').setRanges(range).build();


  rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);

  range ="";
  formula='';
}

}
```

Firstly, i thought maybe the range got from the for loop has the problem.
but when copied the range from the Logger.log() and pasted that range to the setRange's range, it worked.

Here's the code I tried.

[image]

Could you help me figure this out?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to set the conditional format rules for each range with each formula.
- The range is created by the for loop of `for (let i = 3; i < 25; i++) {,,,}`.
- The formula is created by `const formula = '=sum($' + columnStart[z] + '6:$' + columnEnd[z + 6] + '6)>=40';`.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, it seems that `range` of `Logger.log(range)` is the string value. But when `setRanges(range)` is used, `range` is required to be the Range object. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- And, in your situation, how about the following flow?

  1. Put each range to an array of `rules` of `rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules()`.

     - For this, in my answer, I used RangeList.
  2. Use `rules` with `sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules)` put outside of the loop.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  let columnStart = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac'];
  let columnEnd = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah', 'ai', 'ai', 'ai', 'ai', 'ai', 'ai', 'ai', 'ai', 'ai'];
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheetname');
  const rules = []; // sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  for (let z = 0; z < columnStart.length; z++) {
    const formula = '=sum($' + columnStart[z] + '6:$' + columnEnd[z + 6] + '6)>=40';
    const rangeList = [];
    for (let i = 3; i < 25; i++) {
      rangeList.push(columnStart[z] + 2 * i + ':' + columnEnd[z + 6] + 2 * i);
    }
    const ranges = sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).getRanges();
    const rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().whenFormulaSatisfied(formula).setBackground('#f4cccc').setRanges(ranges).build();
    rules.push(rule);
  }
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script, `rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();` is used. In this case, the rules are added every run. In this case, I thought that `const rules = [];` might be suitable instead of `rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();`. In this answer, `const rules = [];` is used. If you want to use `rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();`, please modify above script.
- In this answer, I used the range and the formula from your script. If your actual situation is different from them, please modify above script. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [setRanges(ranges) of Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setrangesranges)